# Perform an action when Firebase Notification is not received by the device

Tags: mongodb, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, nodejs-server

I am trying to check if a function or method is being invoked in the server and act accordingly.

I am creating a basic app that notifies people about their financial transactions. I am using Flutter for the app, NodeJS for the server side of things, Firebase Cloud Messaging for Push Notification and React in order to send the data. So far, I've been successful in sending the Notification and displaying a list of notification for the user when using the mobile application.
The whole system works something like this:

1. The message is composed and sent from the react website,
2. The website calls a POST request from the server to send a notification,
3. The POST request then calls the `getMessaging()` function from the Firebase API that sends the notification to that device
4. The mobile application listens for a notification using `onMessage()` as well as `onBackgroundMessage()`. When a notification is received it again calls the server to store some notification data to the database.

The reason I am storing the notification in the database after it is received by the device is so that I know the status of the message I've sent i.e. "delivered". Now, **I am aiming to send an SMS to the device if the notification is not "delivered" after a certain period of time.** However, looking at the workflow, sending the notification and storing notification are two complete separate methods and thus, I am out of ideas. Is there any way to know if a method/function is being invoked and act accordingly. Or should I take some other approach to this scenario? (If yes, could you give some ideas?)

Comment: I guess you would need to create a cloud function that checks the database for a newly stored message on a scheduled basis. If I understand your requirements correctly. May have cost implications though.

Comment: @GrahamD, I want to avoid using cloud functions. Whatever action I need should be done from my own server in NodeJS.

Comment: So why can't you write a Node.js function to run on your server to do the same? I use Node.js for my cloud functions...which is why I said cloud functions.

Comment: Yes, that probably could be done but I have no knowledge or idea about such method. Could you guide me on how I could achieve that? Should I include sockets in my server or any other ideas?

Comment: I can't really help you with code...I presume it is your server sends the fcm notifications and saves the status on its Mongo db. When you send an fcm message, you set a flag and timestamp against the user record on the db. When you receive delivered notification, you clear the flag and timestamp. You should therefore be able to schedule a function to run every few minutes that reads all records awaiting delivery, check the timestamp to see if it is overdue, and send an SMS if it is.

Comment: Thank you for being such a help. I did not particularly use the implementation you mentioned. However, I did come up with a flow on how things could work from ideas you provided. So, thank you again.

Comment: Ok good, glad I helped

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am just trying to aid my future self in need.
Thanks [GrahamD](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10376604/grahamd) for providing me with some ideas. The process of how my code manages it is below:

### **`sendNotification()`**:

This is a `POST` method that sends notification to the mobile application as well as store the data from that notification to a database. When storing to database, I modify my data model to take two more fields:

1. `status`: with values like `sent` & `delivered`
2. `messageID`: unique ID for each message generated by `uuid`.

The action is still running with `getMessaging.send().then()` below.

### `updateNotificationStatus()`

Instead of saving the notification data after being received by the application, I update just the `status` field using this function. Inside the Flutter app, whenever the application receives a message (`onMessage` or `onBackgroundMessage` from Firebase Cloud Messaging), I call this function as a `PUT` method to update the status from `sent` to `delivered` by using the `messageId` that was sent with the notification.

### `getMessaging().send().then()`

Inside the `sendNotification()`, the callback `.then()` calls another method after the notification is sent. This middleware function gets invoked after the set period of time (set inside the code) to check the `status` of the `messageId` that was just sent. If the `status` has been changed to `delivered`, no action is taken. However, if the `status` remains unchanged (i.e: `sent`), then I can code the action I want to perform.

The back and forth of function invocations is still a headache for me to explain as well as understand. Hopefully, this is understandable and can help out others looking for the answers.